# I am trying to find the page id of a page in Figma and map it to the object id in Google Slides

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, figma-api

**Problem**: I got `args.JSON` from Figma API and I am trying to pull only the string “id” from the child array. I’m using google app script and Figma API to create a plugin. I want all the pages in Figma with their respective id to appear in google app script’s slides.

Reference: how I got the [Pages Array from Figma API](https://itnext.io/figma-web-api-c581ba769e04)

[Figma API](https://www.figma.com/developers/api)

[Figma Pagenode](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/PageNode/)

[Google App Script Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides)

Figma page conversion:

```js
var children = args = {
    "document": {
      "children": [{
            "id": "0:1",
            "name": "Layouts",
            "type": "CANVAS",
                          }]}}

var page = args.document.children;
JSON.page = [];
for (var i in page) {
  JSON.pages.unshift([1]);
};

var pageId = args.page.id;
idJSON.page.id = [];
for (var i in id) {
  idJSON.id, push(pages[i].("id"))
};
```

Google App Script Slide Create:

```js
function createSlide(presentationId) {
  // You can specify the ID to use for the slide, as long as it's unique.
  var pageid = page.stringify(id[0])

  var requests = [{
    'createSlide': {
      'objectId': {
        'insertionIndex': {
          'slideLayoutReference': {
            'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }];

  var slide = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ 'requests': requests }, presentationId());
  Logger.log('Created Slide with ID: ' + slide.replies[0].createSlide.objectId);
}
```

I tried using the shift method to get only the id but it ran an error I’m not sure what method to use.

I tried filtering all the id out of the page using `idJSON.id,filter(("id"))` and it ran but iit cause ab error on my `JSON.pages.unshift([1]);` and I still haven't been able to pass `pageID` into my `var = slide`.

I also tried running my variable `PageID` within and function and it worked as well however I still haven't been able to pass `pageID` into my `var = slide`.
idJSON.id,filter(function(pageId){})

Error (in Google app script):

> TypeError: Cannot call method "unshift" of undefined.
>   at fuctionn3(filename:53)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to turn var2 into a variable to capture the ID from var1. to `unshift` the string from the var1's array. then you want to use the `concate` with var 2 and var 3 give your slide an id.

## Here is the code

```
function strings() {
  var var2 = {};
  var var1 = args.document.children;
  pageJSON.page = [];
  for (var i in page) {
    pageJSON.page.push(page[1].id);
  }

  function createPresentation(NewSlides, Slide) {
    var NewSlides = pageJSON.concat(Slide);
    var presentation = Slides.Presentations.create({
      title: "MyNewPresentation"
    });
    Logger.log("Created presentation with ID: " + presentation.s);

    function createSlide(presentationId, NewSlides) {
      // You can specify the ID to use for the slide, as long as it's unique.
      var pageid = page.stringify(id[0]);

      var requests = [
        {
          createSlide: {
            objectId: {
              insertionIndex: {
                slideLayoutReference: {
                  predefinedLayout: "TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ];
      var var3 = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(
        { requests: requests },
        presentationId(NewSlides)
      );
      Logger.log(
        "Created Slide with ID: " + slide.replies[0].createSlide.objectId
      );
    }
  }
}
```